# I would like to know how to test a page locally when Jquery loads a json file?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

Hi I have a strange problem with where I host my website. Once every now and then the server goes down for no reason. I would like to know how I can avoid this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/.../strQnA.JSON. 
Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I am testing with chrome. I don't want to have to upload my file every 5 min for test.

here is the code I use

```
var url ="strQnA.JSON";
var jsonQnA = jQuery.parseJSON(
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url, 
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).responseText
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files option

Answer (score 3):

You can't avoid issues when a server goes down, but you can implement the error callback for when the AJAX fails to receive a response. From there, you should be able to programmatically resolve the issue during such a case (such as set a timeout to retry after x seconds, etc.).

Comment: This was useful, I'll try that later. I really had a problem with loading the file to get it parsed and then use it to write data in fields. when offline.